# VBA Copy and Paste in another Sheet from AutoFilter outputting one row

Tags: vba, excel, copy, excel-2010

I have an `AutoFilter` that once it is applied it *always* outputs one `row`. I want to `copy` this one `row` and `paste` it on another `Sheet`.

I have considered:

- `xlCellTypeAllValidation` but it throws out an `error`
- `xlCellTypeSameValidation` there are many validation criteria an `AutoFilter`
- `xlCellTypeLastCell` but it gives the location of the last `cell` in the filtered `row`

How can i do this?

Here is an excerpt from my `code`:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(k).Range("A1:AZ1")
        .Value = .Value
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Rev_1
        .AutoFilter field:=11, Criteria1:=Beginnings(k)
        .AutoFilter field:=12, Criteria1:=End_Instnts(k)

        For zz = 13 To last_Field
            .AutoFilter field:=zz, Criteria1:=""
        Next zz
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Select
        .Range.Select

     ThisWorkbook.Sheets(k).AutoFilterMode = False


End With
```

Comment: This isn't chat. Put a bit more thought into your comments please. Or don't comment at all. And especially don't spam the same comment at multiple people - that's just rude. Nobody's interested in your Google Drive anyway.

Comment: @BoltClock you have deleted my comment which actually explained the error as well as other ones which clarified and supported it so thanks, much appreciated. While I wanted to use the comments section to clarify the problem and was about to post an actual answer instead of just guessing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend testing to ensure something actually matched the criteria before you copy - something like:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(k).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 52)
    .Value = .Value
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Rev_1
    .AutoFilter field:=11, Criteria1:=Beginnings(k)
    .AutoFilter field:=12, Criteria1:=End_Instnts(k)

    For zz = 13 To last_Field
        .AutoFilter field:=zz, Criteria1:=""
    Next zz
    ' make sure there are results matching filter
    If .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
        ' offset and resize to avoid headers then copy
        .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets("other sheet").Range("A1")
    End If

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(k).AutoFilterMode = False

End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select all filtered region and then copy it, it will copy visible rows only anyway. Or combine it with .SpeciallCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Smthng like (after End With) (assuming data starts from Row 2)

```
Range("A2:AZ1").Copy Destination:=PasteRange
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use Special Cells targeting visible cells only. One really quick and painless variant is to just use offset.

See the following:

```
Sub CopyFilterResult()

    Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set WS1 = .Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set WS2 = .Sheets("Sheet2")
    End With

    'Apply your filters here.

    WS1.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Copy WS2.Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Screenshots:

**Source (with filter):**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Something to keep as a an alternative.

Let us know if this helps.

**EDIT:**

This code is as per exchange in comments. Read the comments and modify it to suit your needs.

```
Sub CopyAfterFilterMk2()

    Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet
    Dim RngBeforeFilter As Range, RngAfterFilter As Range
    Dim LCol As Long, LRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set WS1 = .Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set WS2 = .Sheets("Sheet2")
    End With

    With WS1
        'Make sure no other filters are active.
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        'Get the correct boundaries.
        LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LCol = .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
        'Set the range to filter.
        Set RngBeforeFilter = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LRow, LCol))
        RngBeforeFilter.Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="o"
        'Set the new range, but use visible cells only.
        Set RngAfterFilter = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LRow, LCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        'Copy the visible cells from the new range.
        RngAfterFilter.Copy WS2.Range("A1")
        'Turn off the filter.
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

This code handles multiple rows post-filter as well.

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: Dear @Nanashi it is indeed a solution but considering that i will surely counter situation where i will have 4 `rows` as a result of `AutoFilter` usage isn't there a way to copy everything that is `Autofiltered` from one `row` to many and `paste` them in another `sheet`?

Comment: See my comment above, alongside @mehow's comment. He is indeed correct. This is a pretty workaround, but [one of the] proper way(s) to do this is to bound your range sans headers, then use `.SpecialCells` on it.